# Catching/Logging ASP.NET front-end exceptions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, log4net

I have an ASP.NET application that has been configured to catch all unhandled exceptions relating to the API it needs to communicate with.

However, I need to catch all unhandled exceptions that are thrown outside the context of the API (i.e front-end exceptions).

I have the following method in my global.asax class that should handle and log exceptions.

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        log.Fatal("Service Desk Error", Server.GetLastError());
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        Server.ClearError();
        Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");
    }
```

While I believe this code should get the job done, I need to be able to test that front-end exceptions are being caught  and logged using this method.

Does anyone know of a bonafide way of testing if this code catches and logs exceptiions? I have a separate class for catching/logging API-related exceptions, I tested by throwing exceptions in my controller classes. What's the best way to throw/log exceptions on the front-end layer?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.